# airflow - how to set the time on the web ui's tree view to UTC?

Tags: user-interface, web, workflow, pipeline, airflow

I'm starting out with apache airflow and have a DAG up and running.

Now I'm using the web ui to monitor the DAG runs and I cannot understand the time shown on the tree view page. This image illustrates my situation:

[image]

I don't understand the time axis shown on marker (3) on the image. The ui's time seems to be in UTC, as shown on marker (1). The selected interval is set to `2017-07-11 12:06:25` as shown on marker (2). The DAG runs depicted on the image have executed at around 11h 12h, so I cannot understand why it says 07PM on the temporal axis in the UI (marker 3). Is this expected behavior? Is the UI picking up another time zone for the diagram?

Apart from this everything seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 3):

Even though airflow is a very useful and highly customizable due to nature of written fully in python; the same thing was an issue I have been struggling with.

Unfotunately Airflow Web UI is only cpable of using UTC time. It is been indicated on their official documentation too.

In, https://airflow.apache.org/timezone.html you'll find

> Please note that the Web UI currently only runs in UTC.

Probably a custom implementation is required to do that.
I will post here when this feature is added or if I would find a solution.